# why it says "this row is bound to another table" when i tried to fetch a convert a DataGridViewRow to DataRow?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following line to create a `DataRow` from a `DataGridViewRow`, the `DataGridViewRow` is fetched when the user clicks the `checkbox` in the `DataGridViewCheckboxColumn`

```
private void dgvAvailableCourses_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)dgvAvailableCourses.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row
}
```

dgvAvailableCourses - `DataGridview`

when I run the above line it says, this row is bound to another table, how do I fix this? I need this row to create a `DataRow` for a `DataTable`

even when I use `dr` in a different way, still gives the same error

```
    private void dgvAvailableCourses_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgvAvailableCourses.DataSource;
                        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    }
```

thanks

Comment: if you are thinking about dr being DataReader, no I don't have DataReaders in this class : )

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. I didn't get any error. Can you post the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: here is the stack trace

Comment: > SMSV100.exe!SMSV100.FrmNewProgram.dgvAvailableCourses_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 215 C#
  [External Code] 
  SMSV100.exe!SMSV100.Program.Main() Line 19 + 0x1d bytes C#
  [External Code]

Comment: here is the youtube video of my debugging http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhrYOUNMRBQ&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a CancelEdit / EndEdit to query on your source, as the row is being in edit Mode I believe.

```
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex];
(dr.RowState == RowState.Modified){
 dr.EndEdit();
}
//Access the row data here
DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)dgvAvailableCourses.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row
```

Comment: still the problem exists, I have posted a video to youtube please read the comments under my original post : )

Comment: the row bound to another table problem solved, it was stupid of me, I've haven't assign the second table to the dgvselectedCourses and with the user of importRow() problem is solved : )